# Unable to write all values of list to CSV row. values are extracting from page and store in variables but missing in File

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Values are **scraped** correctly from webpage but when I am trying to write in CSV as a row company name didn't write in file.

Here is link to webPage : http://search.sunbiz.org/Inquiry/CorporationSearch/SearchResultDetail?inquirytype=EntityName&directionType=Initial&searchNameOrder=A%201421260&aggregateId=domp-142126-360258c3-c08b-4f9a-8866-ad3ecdedef02&searchTerm=A&listNameOrder=A%201421260

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from json import loads
import csv

def writeFile(data):
    with open("A.csv", "a") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(data)

def company_page(url):
    docnum, fenum, fdate, edate, status, levent, companyName, year = '','','','','','','',''
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    # print(soup.prettify())
    reqDiv = soup.find("div", class_ = "detailSection filingInformation")
    companyName = soup.find("div", class_ = "detailSection corporationName").text

    for lab in reqDiv.select("label"):

        if(lab.text == 'Document Number'):
            docnum = lab.find_next_sibling().text
        if(lab.text == 'FEI/EIN Number'):
            fenum = lab.find_next_sibling().text
        if(lab.text == 'Date Filed'):
            fdate = lab.find_next_sibling().text
        if(lab.text == 'Effective Date'):
            edate = lab.find_next_sibling().text
            year = lab.find_next_sibling().text.split('/')[2]
        if(lab.text == 'Status'):
            status = lab.find_next_sibling().text
        if(lab.text == 'Last Event'):
            levent = lab.find_next_sibling().text
        else:
            continue

        details = []
        details.append(companyName)
        details.append(docnum)
        details.append(fenum)
        details.append(fdate)
        details.append(edate)
        details.append(status)
        details.append(levent)
        writeFile(details)
```

Getting the following values in csv [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/acUjN.png

I want company name also in csv file. It stores in variable companyName but can't write in csv.

Comment: that part ? `Florida Profit Corporation`

Comment: yes complete name 

Florida Profit Corporation
CORPORATION A

Comment: This is just one page i am basically scrapping many companies and if I will be successful in this then definitely for other pages as well

Comment: `soup.find("div", class_="detailSection corporationName").get_text(
        strip=True, separator=" ")`

Comment: It's working. you write a code for me yesterday kindly add loop as well Here is the link to that problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826430/scraping-from-dropdown-with-scroll?noredirect=1#comment107624736_60826430

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def Main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.find("div", class_="detailSection corporationName").get_text(
        strip=True, separator=" ")
    data = [item.string for item in soup.select(
        "div.detailSection.filingInformation span")]
    del data[5]
    # print(data[2:-2])
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Name", "Document Number",
                         "FEI/EIN Number", "Date Filed", "Status", "Last Event"])
        writer.writerow([name, *data[2:-2]])


Main("http://search.sunbiz.org/Inquiry/CorporationSearch/SearchResultDetail?inquirytype=EntityName&directionType=Initial&searchNameOrder=A%201421260&aggregateId=domp-142126-360258c3-c08b-4f9a-8866-ad3ecdedef02&searchTerm=A&listNameOrder=A%201421260")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/f663b888c83503f9d3c0c63a72381a3b/data.csv)

[image]